# What is keys inside /etc/ssh/ used for?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-9.10

Can any body please explain the use of the key put in /etc/ssh/?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keys named ssh_host_*_key in /etc/ssh are ssh host keys and are used to verify the authenticity of the host when someone is connecting to it. This mechanism also protects from Man-In-The-Middle Attacks.

http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ssh-host-key-protection
https://serverfault.com/search?q=ssh+host+keys